# How to include the static HTML results of a dynamic Javascript page in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, include

I have a small script that pulls HTML from another site using Javascript.

I want to include that static HTML that gets pulled in a PHP page **without** *any* of the Javascript code appearing in the final PHP page that gets displayed.

I tried doing an include of the file with the Javascript code in the PHP page, but it just included the actual Javascript and not the **results** of the Javascript.

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to fetch the page, execute the JavaScript in it, then extract the data you wanted from the generated DOM.

The usual approach to this is to use a web automation tool such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't.

You need to understand that PHP and Javascript operate on different places, PHP on the server and Javascript on the client.

Your only solution is to change the way all this is done and use "file_get_contents(url)" from PHP to get the same content your javascript used to get. This way, there is no javascript anymore and you can still pre-process your page with distant content.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using "file_get_contents" instead of "include" to fetch the page with Javascript but it's not fetching anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Mathieu points at the part that says: "and use file_get_contents(url) from PHP"... It's not javascript, it's PHP, you have to use this function to get the content of a file or url and put it in a php variable...

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do this directly from within PHP, since you'd need to run Javascript code.

I'd suggest passing the URL (and any required actions such as click event, etc) to a headless browser such as [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), and capturing the DOM from it once the JS engine has done it's work.

You could also use a real browser, but of course you don't need a UI in your case, and it might actually get in the way of what you're trying to do, so a headless browser might be better.

This sort of thing would normally be used for automated testing of a site (ie Functional Testing).

There is a PHP tool named [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/) which can run these sorts of scripts from within a PHP program. It is aimed at writing test scripts, but I would imagine you could use it for your purposes.

Hope that helps.